# Why are some dungeons not clearing for me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Skyrim determine if a dungeon is “cleared”](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/how-does-skyrim-determine-if-a-dungeon-is-cleared)

I just completed a quest for Falk Firebeard in which I had to clear Wolfskull Cave. I cleared it completely, returned to him, got the reward. However, it is not marked as Cleared.

Similarly with Brinewatter Grotto: I killed everyone inside except the friendly Argonian, and it isn't Cleared.

Both were used in quests (which weren't radiant AI ones) so I assume they aren't going to be reused.