# Where can I find a full list of dungeons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In order to [figure out how each dungeon is cleared](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/how-does-skyrim-determine-if-a-dungeon-is-cleared), it would be very nice to have a full list of them. I have heard that there are 130, is that correct? Where can I find a list of dungeons in Skyrim?

UESP seems to list places in general, but has no dungeons category. Wikia, the site I don't really trust these days, seems to list [only 14 dungeons](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Skyrim:_Dungeons); but given that there would be I think that is unfinished...

Comment: On a side note, it's strange that Skyrim considers Giant Camps as dungeons

Comment: Each dungeon has a boss type figure, once they are killed it counts as cleared. You don't need to kill every single enemy in it. Some cannot be cleared though, mostly quest related ones. I have cleared 192 dungeons in my log so far, and have found 336 places. I believe there is about 250 or so locations that can be cleared total.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's [a list of the clearable locations](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Clearable) on UESP.

And [I like this map](http://www.gamebanshee.com/skyrim/mapofskyrim.php) to find them all.

Answer (score 3):

These are all the locations in Skyrim. [http://www.realsg.com/2011/11/guide-skyrim-complete-locations-map.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20111205225356/http://www.realsg.com/2011/11/guide-skyrim-complete-locations-map.html)

I've counted over 530 locations. I would say there is definitely 130 or more dungeons.

I believe a dungeon is cleared when you kill every enemy within the dungeon. There may be an undead on a wall behind a locked door, or a passage that was hidden well. Check your dungeon map when re-exploring.

Comment: To the review queue: I originally rejected this edit and can longer process, but the link appears to be dead and/or possibly malicious now

Comment: @Wondercricket Thanks - seems like its a weird dead link.  I switched it to an archived copy from Wayback which seems to be ok.