# Skyrim Dungeons Respawn

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do dungeons repopulate?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34964/do-dungeons-repopulate)

While I have not played Skyrim yet I have heard some disturbing news on clearing dungeons.  I have heard that once you clear a dungeon it is marked that the dungeon has been cleared on the map which it nice but the not so nice part is that I have heard that at least in 1 case, the dungeon did not re-spawn (instead it was filled with freindly NPCs after being cleared).  Can anyone confirm if this is true and whether or not this applied to all dungeons or maybe just a few certain ones?

I use to re-run certain dungeons when I was in need or a particular item.  For instance, certain dungeons were filled with people carrying arrows so if I needed them I would just go back to the dungeons every once in a while to stock up on them.  If I can't do this anymore, that would really suck.