# Will items in your home despawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know once you have purchased a home you can leave items in the chests inside for easy storage.  My question is regarding the surrounding tables and shelves - if I remember correctly from Oblivion you could leave items on the tables and shelves and they would remain. I'm planning on trying this with a not "super needed" item and seeing if it disappears but I just wanted to ask the community if they have tried this and what the results were.

Comment: I left the dagger keening in my house, left and came back and it was glitched in the wall and I could take it out. So I left and came back again and now it's completely gone

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, they will not. The [in-game help guide even mentions this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35387/safely-store-items-in-gerdurs-house/35406#35406):

> After purchasing a house, you can safely leave your items inside — They will always be there when you return.

Comment: Thank you, now to find a nice place for all these skulls.

Comment: Although i did it in my game , and when I came back to it, the items had fallen on the floor!! Not sure if im the only person this has done it to, or why! x x x x

Comment: @Heather Oblivion was notorious for the collision game logic "launching" things that were close to each other or in a tight spot when a room loaded. Mods to lock things in place were popular, and if Skyrim has the same problem, expect to see similar mods for it before long!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie — Based on what's happening in my own home, I don't think anything's getting launched.  Instead, everything I've placed (vs. what came with the house) seems to be getting reset to *wherever it was when I first dropped it*.  Very odd!

Comment: @Ben That's very interesting. I bet they're storing the drop location, perhaps as a fix for launching problems. Once that feature is reverse engineered, it should be useful for decoration mods…

Comment: @ben That's actually been occurring in my home as well, I have purchased all the "upgrades" and now they don't see to do that as long as they are not on top of a usable item. (ex. frequently used chest) I'm currently building a jega-esq tower on one of my bed side tables and it is keeping form after reloads and frequent house in's and out's. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a now-known bug, a year later. It is indeed storing the drop location. You have to do something like drop it, position it where you want it, leave, come back in, and leave again before the game will remember the new location for an object.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this with a lute and a bee in a jar and so far so good :)

Comment: How many in-game days has the lute and bee been there?

Answer (score 2):

I also dropped some stuff at a shop and it is still there.  I also dropped a few books and a dagger on the street and I guess the people of whiterun don't like books and a weapon cause it is still there to this day.

I find that whenever I drop something in a store, it is given to me by the store owner. They say something like "Hey, you dropped this. I figured you wanted it back," and then it says item(s) added and it's in my inventory.

Comment: This is true until you load a different game/save; if you load a save from another world, the world's 'trash' is cleaned up, and only properly saved items (like home inventories) are permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they will disappear, but when I place my items in my home and return, I find them everywhere but where I put them.