# Book Disappeared Off Surface When Left in Home

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I left the book Kodlak's Journal in my Breezehome, sitting top of the bedroom dresser upstairs. However, upon next inspection of the area after leaving and coming back, the journal was gone. I didn't think this would happen since a purchased home does not respawn items. Is it simply somewhere else in the house, and I need to search for it? An answer from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/will-items-in-your-home-despawn) by BoseBorre leads me to believe the journal has been moved to a random location somewhere inside.

If this is not the case, what happened to the journal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will items in your home despawn?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/will-items-in-your-home-despawn)

Comment: @StrixVaria This person is asking what *actually* happened to his item, he says that he already knows that items don't despawn in your home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inexplicable graphical glitch in Skyrim where items will be found invisible. I'm not sure if items can *turn* invisible, but try to interact with the space in which you left the book. Also, make sure that you thoroughly check your inventory/chests. You may have just misplaced the book.

Comment: and the bookshelf if you have the alchemy room purchased.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes objects will turn invisible, though I've only encountered that behavior after taking an object. If that is the case, it should still be there, and dragging it (Hold E when you get the prompt to read it) will make it visible again.

If it's not there, then the book is likely to have moved to where you've dropped it or fallen through the object it was on.