# Is it safe to leave my stuff in a random chest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I safely store my stuff?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff)

I don't have a house yet in Skyrim. If I leave my junk in a chest in a dungeon, will it remain there indefinitely? Will it disappear at some point?

Comment: This question has been asked before. Check http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff for example.

Comment: @Konerak That question asks *where* to store items. This question asks if it's a good idea to store items in chests scattered throughout Skyrim.

Comment: @Mana *le sigh*

Comment: @IanBoyd I'll reopen if you think so, but I'm uncertain of the difference. "Where can I safely store my stuff" implies that a good answer will cover where it is both safe and unsafe to store your goods.

Comment: @Ian anywhere that's not safe to store items is, by default, unsafe, is it not?  Since a random chest in a dungeon wasn't the answer, then its not safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your items are not safe - I believe it takes less than 48 in-game hours until the items disappear. The good part is they allow you to start off with a good amount of space in your inventory to hold everything.

Hope that answers your question.