# Can stuff be put safely in your Spouse's House?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it safe to leave your stuff in your wife's house? Or will it disapear in 48 hours like anything in a dungeon?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36256/aside-from-containers-in-bought-houses-are-there-other-safe-containers-which

Comment: If "your spouse's house" is never mentioned in the duplicate question, or subsequent answers, is it the same question?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The answer to the other question is "stuff stored in YOUR house is safe". This question is, "after marrying, does a spouse's house become YOUR house, and thus safe?"

Comment: A simple way to test if your items can be stored safely in your spouses house is to place a non-valuable item there and leave it for a while, checking occasionally to see if it disappears (you can gather all of their items in the house in the meantime) .

Answer (score 6):

Ive had my items stored in my spouses house for around two weeks and they are still there, so, yes I believe containers in your spouses house are safe. EDIT: They have been there for several months now without loss. Your spouse's house is safe.

Comment: Cell reset is longer than two weeks (it's 30 days), so that doesn't prove they're safe.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie he said it's been there several months without reset. That's more than 30 days.

Comment: @Jim It's important to notice the timestamps on edits and comments. In any case, this answer is contradicted by others — it probably depends on *which* spouse you have, since the chest objects don't care about who owns them or whether they're you're spouse, they care about their the reset/no-reset status they are assigned by the developer that placed it.

Answer (score 2):

**Doubtful.** Any house that is not actually one you can buy and call your own in-game would not be safe. Except for certain exceptions, virtually all houses and buildings reset the items in them eventually.

On a relatively unrelative note, some of these exceptions are:

- **Helgen Inn**: "The ruined inn in Helgen features a wardrobe and an end table that can be used for storage, both of which do not reset. The inn also features a perfectly preserved and functional bed. This makes for a very useful shelter at the beginning of the game, however the fort may spawn bandits if not visited for some time."
- **Sleeping Giant Inn**: The chest in the secret Blades room is safe.

Best of luck.

(Source: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses)

Answer (score 1):

Some containers are safe, but not all.  Luckily the chest I put my reagents in didn't reset, but the chest I put my Ore as well as the Barrel I put my food in both reset at least partially.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't store anything in your spouses house. 
After marrying uthguard the unbroken, I stored things in her house. For a little while it worked fine, then one day I came back to empty chests, and all my loot unique items and everything else was gone!!!!
On a separate note, any quest items (the type 
you can't remove from your inventory) remained in the chest. 
I don't know if this was a glitch or not, but it sure pissed me off

Answer (score 1):

yes it is 100% safe you should do it all the time! it also helps if you help her first!

Answer (score -1):

Before I had a house, I kept my stuff in a barrel in Whiterun next to the smith. I guess it was kind of like a safe deposit barrel. :D And nothing ever disappeared from there.

Comment: This isn't an answer.