# What is a reliable way to determine if a container is safe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aside from containers in bought houses or guilds/organizations, are there other 'safe' containers which will store items permanently (won't reset)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36256/aside-from-containers-in-bought-houses-or-guilds-organizations-are-there-other)

Is there any reliable way to determine if a storage container in Skyrim is safe to store items in (as in, they won't disappear after a while)?

Somebody hinted towards the IsOwner console command in another question, but I fear it is not a valid suggestion, since it always seems to return " is not the owner.".

Comment: What containers are you trying "isOwner" on? I think that's your best bet, honestly.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: I've tried it on various containers as well as some items. I noticed it returns a false on everything but my horse - Frost.

As far as the question Mark Trapp linked is concerned: it queries concrete examples, I'm looking for a general way to check any and all containers if they're safe.

Answer (score 1):

Any houses that you own are safe. Any guild lodgings that are provided for you are safe. companions are safe(as long as they dont get killed without you knowing). It is always risky to store items in places that do not belong to you as the container could be reset or an NPC could take from the container.

Comment: But is there an actual way to determine this other than trying a container out?

Comment: those should be the only safe containers in the game... if you are storing items in a container that isn't one of these your items will, eventually, disappear.