# Is the Guild Tribute Chest a safe storage

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that The Skyrim manual states:

> WARNING! Do not leave things in containers you do not own! They may not be there when you come back for them. Buying a house is one way of own containers.

After the thieves guild quest, and side quests, to become guild master I have a key to the tribute chest so I guess I own it.  But that chest resets with tribute

My questions are is it safe to store stuff in the tribute chest?  How about the bed chest, which have been empty since I raided them the first day at the thieves guild? What did you expect, I am thief.

The reason I ask is because I have about 30-50k in potions I just made and the members of the guild seem to be the largest source of vendors with coin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I safely store my stuff?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff)

Comment: I respectfully disagree since that post, which I looked at, did not mention any of the thieves guild chests.

Comment: Sorry, we have so many questions on this topic I think I chose the wrong one.  The discussion in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36256/aside-from-containers-in-bought-houses-or-guilds-organizations-are-there-other lets you know how to tell whether something is safe.  And basically, the answer for anything that isn't in your home, is no.  They will appear safe until you manage to trigger the conditions for them to reset, and then you will lose everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not safe.
You may be lucky and it'll remain untouched for a while, but you risk losing all its contents anytime.

See here: [Where can I safely store my stuff?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is absolutely not! I learned this the hard way. I completed the main storyline (dragonborn quest line) and therefore collected the two or so dragon priest masks you get through that quest line. I stored them, along with several other things in the guild master's chest where I had them for yonks. One day, when I got the latest official game update for the ps3, which fixed certain bugs, I found out that all the items in the guild masters chest were gone. I can't get them back.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe ones are when you travel back in time at the labrinthian, or if you own a house

Answer (score 0):

No, a container is safe if it doesn't respawn. The tribute chest's entire point is that it respawns to hold some nice treasure. It is the very definition of unsafe storage.