# Can I carry things inside of monsters?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Based on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41686/5624) I wonder - can I kill .... a rat, put all my things inside of him and just push him to nearest city (without slowing down) then extract my stuff and sell them?

Comment: one of of "pushing" would be to throw fireballs at the rat (it would also make mastering of destruction easier)

Comment: You can only gain skill points for something that can take damage.  So a dead rat does not count.

Comment: There's a way to grab stuff: Holding `E` on PC. I'm not sure what button it is for the consoles.

Comment: Consoles it is your action button, but believe me when I say it is VASTLY inferior to the way it works in PC.

Comment: I'd be worried that as a non-safe/owned container, the contents may reset without your knowledge.

Answer (score 36):

Yes it's possible. Rather than trying to use the physics object grab or spamming Fus Ro Dah however, a better choice is to use one of the 'raise dead' spells from the Conjuration school. This will allow your Skeever Suitcase (or Bandit Backpack, Draugr Drawer, Vampire Valise, Necromancer Knapsack, Stormcloak Satchel, or even Legionairre Luggage - whatever is handy really) to follow you through cave, town, building, and zone entrances, offering much more versatility.

Comment: "Draugr Drawer" is disgusting and doesn't mean what you think it means

Comment: @OrigamiRobot It means [exactly what I think it means.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawer_(furniture)) You, on the other hand, seem to have an underwear fixation.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - Well I DO wear them daily so you may be onto something.

Comment: Except when the Raise Dead wears off, won't they turn into a pile of dust?   Can you still push a pile of dust?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, yes it is possible.  How you do this varies from fireballs to FUS'RO'DAHing him all the way home.

Only way I see this not working is if it is inside a dungeon (read: an area that requires a loading screen to get in/out of) the body would probably be permanently stuck inside the area.

Comment: Since most cities are behind a loading screen, that's a pretty big limitation.

Comment: Aye, he asked for a way to get back to town, so fast travel to just outside (say a stable) is still viable.