# Will zombies follow me through fast travel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I create a zombie, and then fast travel somewhere, will it follow me or be left behind?

Answer (score 3):

They generally do i.e. they are meant to. But as you may have realised Skyrim is rather glitchy/buggy and they just seem to disappear into nothingness sometimes. So quick save before you fast travel and it really helps.

Also, I am guessing you are referring to dead thralls....

Comment: I was thinking more of a Reanimated Zombie, actually. I found out that I had left my items in an unsafe container. As I can't afford a house, I was thinking of using the procedure outlined [in this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41689/can-i-carry-things-inside-of-monsters) to take my items to a safe location. Unfortunately, they're too heavy for me and even my companion to lift, and I want the items out of the chest as quickly as possible.

Comment: What i did early on is after say the dungeon is cleared I'd collect everything and be WAY over encumbered but walk out uber slow and get on my HORSE,since you CAN fast travel while Overly Encumbered on a horse, just FYI

Comment: I concur with this answer. Reanimated corpses will usually follow you through Fast Travel, even over long distances while carrying treasure, then crumble into dust once you get there. Chests are safe for a while, but sell some of that junk and buy the Whiterun house as soon as possible, for the safe container.

Comment: I've had hit-or-miss experience with this one -- sometimes my zombies (don't have thralls yet) wait to crumble to dust until I arrive at my fast travel destination, other times they don't (and on one occasion -- a relatively short fast-travel -- I found the ash pile while walking back along the route). No rhyme or reason to it that I can see.