# What is the benefit of owning a house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I missing something by not owning a home?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41831/am-i-missing-something-by-not-owning-a-home)

I was about to buy a house in Skyrim, but then I saw that it was 5 grand to buy it.

was just wondering what I would actually gain from buying a house. What is in the house? Do I get storage or a grinding stone or anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you buy a house, you can [sleep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping) there and store your stuff [without fear that it will disappear](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containers#Safe_Containers).

A basic house contains a bed and a chest for your things. You can buy improvements such as a cooking pot, alchemy table, tanning rack, additional storage, etc.

The improvements available to you vary by the town you buy the house in. They're described in detail [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses) along with the prices for each house and its upgrades.

Other than that, you also get an achievement (Citizen) for buying a house.