# Is the chest outside High Hrothgar safe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am on a new character, I would like to lay off buying Breezehome for a while. Can I store some of my items in the offering chest outside High Hrothgar? I noticed that it never respawns items. Lore-wise, Klimmek appears to be the only NPC who touches that chest, so it should be safe. However, any of you used it for long term storage, ever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I safely store my stuff?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe that chest to be safe and is tied directly to a quest. I would suggest checking out [this page here.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses#Free_Shacks) It lists all the currently known locations in the world with 'safe' storage that will not reset... My personal favourite is the [Alchemist's Shack](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemist%27s_Shack).

Comment: You can store items on the bodies in the Abandoned Shack and they won't disappear.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not safe.  You must purchase a house if you want to have an absolutely safe place to store things.  Otherwise you need to retrieve the item before that area is respawned.

Comment: No need to purchase a house, you can have a free room in Winterhold for example

Comment: @Juan Several comments on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff beg to differ.

Comment: Opinion is divided in that link. I, for one, know by experience that they don't reset. Perhaps it's a random boolean that gets set when you first install the game... we'll never know... we'll never know

Comment: I've gone and did a isowner check on those containers and you definitely aren't the owner of those in the winterhold room, whether or not they reset is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have stored items in that chest every play through until I bought a house and I never lost a thing