# Is it really worth hoarding all the loot you find?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

By level 49, I have collected hundreds upon hundreds of various items during my quest.  I have accumulated so much loot, in fact, that I need to use 6 barrels in Riverwood to categorize my wide assortment of stash, each one heaping full with armor, weapons, gems, jewelry, potions, ingredients, ore, ingots, magic books, scrolls, and other miscellaneous items that carry a good sell value.  If I were to follow through with my plan and sell off everything I have, I'd easily walk away with 50k+ in gold.  There's just one small problem...

...no merchant is rich enough for my patronage =\.

In fact, I don't think all the merchants in all of Skyrim combined are rich enough.

I know there are perks I can get that allow me to sell a wider range of items to vendors that would be otherwise uninterested and perks that will put more gold in the vendors' pockets, but no perk will give me the edge I need to completely liquidate my inventory.

What is one to do?  Simply stop collecting loot since no one in Skyrim can afford to buy it?

Comment: Come on. You don't want to, say, [get to the $%^&ing broom dungeon and be like "why didn't I pick up all those brooms?"](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/11/14)

Comment: http://www.collegehumor.com/video/6747386/skyrim-hoarders

Comment: You people do know that Oblivions Shivering Isles expansion had a [quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Shivering:Work_is_Never_Done) where you had to gather 50 calipers and 50 tongs? Finally all the hoarding paid off

Comment: if you're really motivated to move your junk, just keep fast-travelling across the country, your merchants gold supply will restock every so often.

Comment: You better not have a collection of spoons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I sell as I loot.  The merchants seem to get more cash every day or so.  So if I have a big haul I sell what I can and I keep a special chest just for stuff I know I want to sell.  So if I have a day in town I do nothing but hang out at the pub drinking, or spend crafting or something, I go back to that chest and sell more the next day.

Plus you can trade instead of sell, buy soul gems or alchemy ingredients or such that will always be useful.

Of course at nine barrels of loot you are way behind.  Fast travel to vendors in each city?

Comment: This is definitely what I wish I had done, sold as I go, and probably the only solution to my issue.  Another issue, though, is that I like to hoard weapons and improve/enchant them in bulk later.  I really wish merchants would carry more gold.

Comment: Well, if you are playing on Windows you can find some mods in the Steam Workshop for Skyrim that enhance merchants so they may have more money.  One I saw browsing quickly is called Dynamic Merchants.  It isn't a blantant cheat either, the rationale is that the more you deal with a merchant, the more successful and prosperous they are, so they more money they will get.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "every day or so" is approximately two days. Usually if you make a full tour of all the shops in skyrim, you will have run out the refresh timer by the time you get back to the first one. If not, just wait two days and go again.

Answer (score 14):

fellow Skyrim hoarder!

First, you want to move all that stuff to your own house in Whiterun. The barrels are [not guaranteed safe in the long term](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff). There are numerous chests and other storage items, including bookshelves, end tables and sacks.

You can gradually liquidate your stock by selling little at a time, and fast travelling between towns to sell your junk. Shops eventually recover their gold, so sell a little of your junk every time you visit the city. Buy everything you can first, because that'll increase the seller's current money, so you can sell more things.

Another trick is that some shopkeepers (such as the alchemist shop in Whiterun) also give skill training. Money you spend on training goes into the seller's current funds, which lets you sell a lot more.

Some stuff is useful, so it's worth hoarding. Alchemical items can be used to craft hundreds of potions in one go and max out Alchemy. All those ancient Nord swords can be enchanted in one sitting to raise Enchanting, ingots to make weapons, and so forth.

Stop picking up truly useless items, though. Especially ignore junk with a high weight to value ratio and no use, like embalming tools and tankards.

When you're high level and have a lot of gold, you'll run out of things to spend it on. At this point, stop bothering with low-end items like steel or orcish swords. Ignore anything unless it's useful or worth a lot.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ Similarly, if you play Fallout 3 or NV (should do that), money spent repairing items goes into the merchant's current funds.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that the thieves guild is the best place to sell you loot. Even when you just join there is a fence, who buys anything, and has a thousand gold. If you go through the quest line and upgrade the guild, there will be merchants with thousands of gold to buy loot.

Their money supplies will refresh every few days, so you can just go back and keep selling.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in my third (and final) play-through.  I load up on stock from my barrels in Riverwood, sell to Alvor, sell to that other guy with the claw, fast travel to Whiterun to sell to that smith, then fast travel to Riften to sell to Grelka, that smith guy, and then save my stolen or non-stolen leftovers to Tonilia.  Works great.

Comment: Also, with Grelka, you can max out on light armor training and then sell her more, so you're basically trading skills for weapons and armor.

Answer (score 5):

Money is not in issue in Skyrim, merchant gold will likely be the limiting factor in how much loot you can move. Cherry-pick what you take home, only take things that are genuinely useful.

Comment: But I love getting Nord and Foresaken arrows.  They rule.  It is so awesome when I run out of other much better arrows in the middle of a dragon fight and it selects something way down the list.

Answer (score 4):

Sell as you go. Always keep what you can carry. Hoarding is pointless in Skyrim. The most gold that you can count on a frequent merchant is *2500 , so don't let it break your mage-heart to sell each of those anchanted swords, bows and heavy armor that are worth 5-10k each for only 1k ... because the items are useless. 
Instead of trying to make money, make the challenge for you to have the most room to pick up the better loot at the next location.

This brings me to merchants. Invest. Don't just sell to them. Buy what you need and sell again to get your money back. At lvl63 (99-legendary Speech) it's tough to have less than 50k gold with me.

If you like the feature of selling items for currency, raise your Speech. The more often you barter, the faster the skill raises. Same as all other skills.

I postulate that most things reset upon leveling up. Playing on higher difficulty is the most rewarding. If you have your top 10 (or 5) places to loot, odds are that once you sell stock that first cave is going to be ready again with better loot.

If you're keeping a spare parts pile at home for enchanting... that's the only reason to keep anything.
Always disenchant before selling.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly I would not loot as much. I generally only loot gold now, because i have a plethora of weapons and armor as well. The only items i generally collect are the daedrict artifacts because they took a while to get all of them. But if collecting loot is your thing, then go for it, just don't look to be able to move it all very well.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not worth hoarding all that stuff.  Once you get the merchant perk in speech and can sell any non-stolen item to any merchant it becomes easy to make money.  Potions can be made and sold to anyone.  An iron dagger with the banish enchanment fetches me thousands at any merchant and I can make it for about 40 septims.

Learn soul trap, learn some enchantments, smith iron daggers, enchant said daggers, profit.

Now, I just make sure to carry around 10 enchanted daggers when I go adventuring.  I loot everything I want, or the most expensive sellable stuff, then when my inventory is full I go back to Whiterun.  I have 4 merchants right by my house to unload that gear onto. I buy all the raw materials they have (as well as any weapons/armor with new enchantments), then I sell my junk/potions/enchanted daggers until they are broke.  Move to the next merchant repeat.  Every time I go to Whiterun I clear out 4 merchants of raw materials and gold, then go to my house to dump all the raw materials.

At some point I am going to legendary my smithing, load up 8,000 lbs worth of smithing supplies, slowly walk next door to the forge, and get my smithing back up to 100 in one session.

I have about 75k gold right now.  Not sure what to do with it.  Eventually I will be buying all the houses and upgrading, but as of now I am making money faster than I know what to do with it.  Especially since I can invest with most merchants.  I instantly get my 500 investment back by selling them enchanted gear, and I get that extra 500 every time I come back too.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution to your hoarding problem, the thing is that you can still pickup anything you see thats not stealing because whats the point of taking low  value stuff when you can only sell it to tonilia. Buy a horse get a bow and arrow and nock an arrow by aiming, by doing this you will walk faster, use whirlwind sprint shout, horse, mainly there are many ways to move fast while over encumbered. Just sell all junk that yoou can to one merchant if you still have some left, move to another merchant and repeat. Enjoy that life of a hoarder bros.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the perk which allows you to sell any kind of item to any merchant, then you can go round selling to all the stall owners in riften, which is just quicker because they're outside, then save all stolen goods for tonillia. :)

Comment: If you read the question closely, the asker is aware of the Merchant perk, but this isn't solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things: start being more selective about what you pick up and sell what you've already picked up.

I'm surprised you have made it to level 49 and are still storing things in Riverwood. You need to stop doing that. Go to Whiterun and buy Breezehome from the Jarl's steward. Then go to the stables outside of Whiterun, buy yourself a horse, and travel back to Riverwood. Sell a few items of jewelry at the Riverwood Trader (that's all he'll be able to buy), then pack everything you own, hop on the horse, and travel back to Whiterun. Encumbrance doesn't matter on a horse, hence the suggestion to buy one.

At Breezehome in Whiterun, I suggest breaking down your items in the following manner: put smithing-related items in one "box" (i.e., ores, ingots, leather/strips and whatever else I'm forgetting right now), unimproved weapons and armor in another "box", and anything that can be immediately sold in a third box. For me, items that can be immediately sold include jewelry, improved weapons and armor, and that category of items I don't need and which can't be improved. Some people like to enchant items before they're sold to increase their value. As for the rest of your vast collection of all other items Skyrim, you can obviously arrange things as you please. One of Breezehome's strengths is the number of storage containers it has which makes it easier to sort things out.

Having done this, your next step should be the alchemy/enchanting hack. I don't know what it's actually called, but it's the process whereby you create fortify enchanting potions, then go to the enchanting table (in this case the one in Dragonsreach) and craft fortify alchemy gear. At the alchemy table again, don your new fortify alchemy gear, and craft a new set of enchanting potions. Notice this set of enchanting potions will be more powerful than the first... allowing you to craft a more powerful set of fortify alchemy gear. You see where this is going. Repeat the process two, three, or four times - until you really can't do much better (for now). If you're not familiar with the ins and outs of the process, Google "Carlsguides Skyrim Enchanting".

The same applies to your Smithing skill. Once you've created the best set of fortify alchemy gear you can at your current Alchemy/Enchanting skill levels, go to your alchemy table and create some fortify smithing potions. Oh, and use the enchanting table to create fortify smithing gear as well. Don't forget that! Now we're coming to the point: back at Breezehome, pick up everything from your first box (i.e., ores, ingots, etc.) and everything from your second box (i.e., unimproved weapons/armor). Go next door, don your fortify smithing gear (note you should have FIVE fortify smithing items, not four), take a fortify smithing potion, and improve your weapons/armor at the grindstone and workbench. You may as well also churn out jewelry at the forge from your stores of silver and gold and your diamonds, emeralds, etc. Obviously you shouldn't waste your ore/ingots on crafting totally new weapons/armor; you have too many as it is.

You'll have accomplished a few happy things through this process: you'll have advanced 10+ levels in your smithing skill and 2+ character levels as well; you'll probably have increased the value (in septims) of a whole category of inventory by 15-20% (rough guess); and you'll have substantially reduced the ore, ingots, and gemstones in your possession.  Lumber to the blacksmith and his apprentice and sell what you can, and then lumber up to Skyforge and sell what you can there, too. Later, you should craft a fortify barter necklace. For now, lumber back to Breezehome and deposit your improved weapons/armor and new set of jewelry into your "sales box" for later sales runs. Merchants' cash/inventory reset every 48 hours.

This is how you START reining in your out-of-control inventory levels.

From here, you would be wise to purchase additional homes. I suggest Honeyside in Riften as your second home. If you have completed the Thieves Guild questline and have also activated all four merchants in the Ragged Flagon, you'll have access to twice the usual number of merchants in Riften as in other cities. This combined with the three perks in the Speech skill tree that relate to increasing the amount of cash merchants have to spend and expanding their product offerings will greatly serve you in your quest to deplete excess stock. When you're ready, pack up maybe half your junk, hop on the horse, and ride to Riften. Then maybe expand to Windhelm, and to Solitude, and Markarth, and elsewhere. By the time you've reached this stage, you won't have an excess inventory problem any more, unless you keep picking up everything you see; what you'll have are smartly set up little business centers in every major town in Skyrim... and you'll be hoarding septims instead!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me so that Looting everything is useless.  What you want to do is this:

1. Buy breezehome in Whitburn (becomes available once you kill the dragon in the main scenario quest)
2. Make sure you buy all the upgrades for it
3. Filter all your loot in different containers So it's easy to know where you left things.

Breezehome is great because it has a quick access to the smithy and other vendors.
I usually only pickup loot with a 1-10 weight/value margin. Meaning if an item's weight is 2 it's value should be 20 or more. Just multiply the weight times 10 or more in order to pick it up.
Also make sure you invest in the perks to increase vendors funds and the one which makes you able to sell everything to everyone.

Happy Looting!