# Can NPCs steal from your home in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the Skyrim Hearthfire DLC, and would like to know if bandit NPCs can steal from my house or not.

Is this possible, and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: If anything goes missing, you can actually blame the dlc.

Comment: I blame @UlfricStormcloak's Nord minions for my missing ebony claw.

Comment: "If anything *gone** missing, you can actually blame the DLC." means that if you save your game as 'normal Skyrim' then reload it with the DLC, lost items can be caused by the DLC itself. As for your missing ebony claw, don't blame to me baby.:)

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak Yes. I know what he meant. It was meant as a joke.

Comment: I know, that's why I called you baby..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** There are no NPCs in Skyrim that will steal items you stored in your home, or any other [safe, non-resetting containers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121584/4797). Even thief and bandit NPCs won't be able to steal those items. Your items should be safe as long as you put them in a [safe, non-resetting container](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121584/4797).

Answer (score -3):

even in the bass game people could take stuff out of containers even if you own them, like if thugs sent by some one you stole from enter your house and start a conflict, they can take weapons and shields from your containers and use them to fight you

Comment: This is not correct.