# Which containers outside of Tundra Homestead are safe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This question is specific to the Creation Club content "Tundra Homestead".

There is an external forge and smithing area next to Tundra Homestead.  Here is a 'screen shot' of some of the containers:

[image: Tundra Homestead External Storage]

I spent a long time away and when I came back, some of the external containers reset (not safe storage, red squares) but some were fine (safe storage, green squares).  I'm now concerned that none of them are actually safe, but I'm not sure what the intent even is now.  I know/understand that the lockbox is safe because [all of them are safe storage throughout the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121584/174247).  However, the rest I am unsure of what the correct expectation should be.  Should I trust none of them (except the lockbox?)  Is this intended behavior of Tundra Homestead or is it a bug? (That may be unanswerable, unless Elanora happens to see this).  I checked the [wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tundra_Homestead) but it says very little about the CC content.

My system is XBox One and I do have mods installed, though none of that should affect this that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Tundra Homestead UESP entry](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tundra_Homestead_(place)#Notes),

> *The exterior barrels and single small sack are not safe for storage.*